# Subquery and subselection for Count/Number doesnt work

Tags: mysql, join, mariadb, subquery

for example, for company (3) and his partners, I need the number of events with payouts. But i get only the number for one partner, im my example i have

[image: Events with payouts for the partners of company]

i have 3 tables (t_company, t_partner, t_event, t_payout).

t_company = the firms
  t_partner =  partner of companies
  t_event  = Events of Companies and Partners
  t_payout  =  prices and payouts for events

t_company:
    `i_company` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `s_caption` VARCHAR(254) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        PRIMARY KEY (`i_company`)

```
  t_partner:
`i_link` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `i_licensee` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `i_partner` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`i_link`),

  t_event:
    `i_event` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `i_dealer_office` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`i_event`)

  t_payout:
    `i_payout` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `s_caption` VARCHAR(254) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `i_category` CHAR(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `n_amount` DECIMAL(9,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `d_time` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `i_event` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `d_date` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`i_payout`),
```

What i need?

1. PartnerIDs of i.e. Company with ID3 (i_partner -> t_partner)
2. Company Name (s_caption -> t_company)
3. Number of Events with Payouts from the partners of Company

QUERY

```
SELECT 
    p.i_partner,
    (select c1.s_caption FROM t_company c1 WHERE c1.i_company = p.i_partner) as s_caption, 
    (SELECT count(*) from t_event e Where e.i_dealer_office = p.i_partner ) as testing
   ,    (
            Select count(*) from (
                SELECT count(payout.i_event) from  t_event e 
                 LEFT JOIN t_payout payout ON payout.i_event = e.i_event
                 WHERE
 e.i_dealer =  p.i_partner 
### here i tried p.i_partner for the partnerIDs but thats doesnt work #### AND payout.d_time > '2018-01-01 00:00:00'
                Group by e.i_event) as result

    )as NumberOfPayouts

    FROM t_company c
    LEFT JOIN t_link_partner p ON p.i_licensee = c.i_company
    WHERE c.i_company = 3  <= the company
    ORDER BY s_caption asc
```

Comment: *i have 3 tables (t_company, t_partner, t_event, t_payout).* I count with a result of 4. And add links info. *What i need?* I cannot find the reason for to use subqueries.

Comment: ok , thanks for feedback, but i have no solution.

Comment: @Akina I ve now found my own solution...thanks anyway

Here my solution...

`select
 t.i_partner, 
 (select t.s_caption from t_company t where t.i_company = t.i_partner ),
(select count(*) from t_event Where t_event.i_dealer = t.i_partner ) as NumberOfPayouts

FROM 
 t_link_partner t, t_event, t_payout, t_company
WHERE
   t_event.i_dealer = t.i_partner AND t_payout.i_event = t_event.i_event AND t_company.i_company=3
group by t.i_partner`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your support, now i found my own solution:

```
    select
       t.i_partner, 
      (select t.s_caption from t_company t where t.i_company = t.i_partner ),
(select count(*) from t_event Where t_event.i_dealer = t.i_partner ) as NumberOfPayouts

FROM 
    t_link_partner t, t_event, t_payout, t_company
WHERE
      t_event.i_dealer = t.i_partner AND t_payout.i_event = t_event.i_event AND t_company.i_company=3
group by t.i_partner
```